# Some of our electonics are being fried

Tags: grounding, electrical-panel

Would having the ground from a 277/480 panel hooked up to the ground of a 120/240 panel have the potential of causing problems, such as fried electronics? [image]

Comment: "Ground from 277 light" should connect to the ground of 277/480 Panel A, **NOT** the ground of some other panel. Mixing 3-phase 277/480 and 2-phase 120/240 ground returns is almost certainly an electrical code violation. **NFPA NEC (2014) 215.6 Feeder Equipment Grounding Conductor.** "Where a feeder supplies branch circuits in which equipment grounding conductors are required, the feeder shall include or provide an equipment grounding conductor in accordance with the provisions of 250.134, to which the equipment grounding conductors of the branch circuits shall be connected...."

Comment: Bottom line, you will need to hire an electrician to upgrade the feeder to panel A to support what you're trying to do.

Comment: How are the two panels fed? Are they separate utility services, or is one a utility service and the other a transformer-derived service?